# How to modify user input in linked list?

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

I'm currently learning how to use linked list in class. I'm only able to add, delete, display and sort data.

Is it possible to edit the data that has been input by user?

Please take a look at the code, is this a possible way to modify it?

To modify the list values I have implemented a simple prompting mechanism, but there is a little problem:

After the user enters the age the program immediately stops working.

```
void node::update()
{
    int updateAge;
    cout << "Please enter age: ";
    cin>>updateAge;
    int ch;
    int a;
    node *current;
    node *temp;
    node *start_ptr;

    if (start_ptr == NULL)
        cout << "No record to update!" << endl;
    else
    {
        current = start_ptr;

        while((current!=NULL) && (current->temp->age!=updateAge))
        {
            current=current->next;
        }
        if (current==NULL)
            {cout<<"The Requested age is Not Found" << endl;}


        else if(current->temp->age==updateAge)
        {
            cout<<"What Information You Want To Update?" << endl;
            cout<<"1. Name" << endl;
            cout<<"2. Height" << endl;
            cin>>ch;
            system("cls");

            switch(ch)
            {
                case 1 :
                {
                    cout << "Enter New Name: ";
                    cin.ignore();
                    getline(cin, current->temp->name);
                    break;
                }

                case 2 :
                {
                    cout<<"Enter New Height: ";
                    cin >> current->temp->height;
                    break;
                }

                default:
                {
                    cout<<"Wrong Input! Please choose again: ";
                    cin>>ch;
                }
            }
            cout<<"RECORD UPDATED !";
        }
    }
}

struct list
{
    list *head, *tail;
    list *next;
};

class node
{
    private:
        std::string name; // Name
        int age; // Age in integer
        float height; // In meters

    public:
        node *next; // Pointer to next node
        node *head, *tail;
        node *start_ptr = NULL; // Start Pointer (root)
        node *temp;
        node *temp2;
        node *pNextValue;
        node* prev; // empty header
        node* current;
        void update();
        void printList();
        void delete_end_node();
        void search();
        void sort_age();
        void deletebyAge();
    node()
        {
            head = NULL;
            tail = NULL;
        }


        void getInput()
        {
            temp = new node;
            cout << "Name: ";
            cin >> temp->name;
            cout << "Age: ";
            cin >> temp->age;
            cout << "Height: ";
            cin >> temp->height;

            cout<<"\n";
            temp->next = NULL; // Sets the node to be the last node
            if (start_ptr == NULL)
                start_ptr = temp;
            else
            {
                temp2 = start_ptr; // We know temp2 is not NULL - list not empty!
                while (temp2->next != NULL) // The loop will terminate when temp2
                    temp2 = temp2->next;        // points to the last node in the list
                                                    // Move to next link in chain
                temp2->next = temp; // Sets the pointer from that last node to point
                                    // to the node that has just declared
            }
        } // End of getInput() function
}; //End of class
```

Comment: Yes, what you want is possible. Since this looks like homework, I'll leave actually doing it to you though. Whether the code snippet you provided does the job is also something only you can decide.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt nope this is not a homework. I'm just using this code to learn more on how to use linked list in class. :)

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the input handling is not very robust. What if the user enters a value other then `1` or `2` ? I suggest you implement a user interacting function which will help you make sure the user input is valid. good luck and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: oh I forgot about that @RannLifshitz

Comment: can you please post the error which you had received when the application crashes? can you also provide the inputs that you used for your execution ?

Comment: The input is already provided in the code. Do I need to show my class too? The error is my program immediately stopped working after user input age. @RannLifshitz

Comment: See @Gellert Lee's answer below buddy :)

Comment: If this is not for educational purposes, classwork or otherwise, may I recommend `std::list`? It's what all the cool kids use. Well, no. Most of them use `std::vector` unless they have a really good reason not to. Linked lists can be hilariously slow.

Answer (score 1):

In your member function `update`, you are redeclaring a new node called `start_ptr` which is not pointing to anything in your list. You should just use `Node *current = start_ptr;` Also there is no point of making a `current` or `temp` variable in your node class.

This is all you need for Node and List:

```
class Node {
public:
    Node() : data(0), prev(nullptr), next(nullptr) {}
    Node(int newData, Node *newPrev, Node *newNext)
    : data(newData), prev(newPrev), next(newNext) {}

    int getData() const { return data; }
    Node *getPrev() const { return prev; }
    Node *getNext() const { return next; }
    void setData(const int& newData) { data = newData; }
    void setPrev(Node *newPrev) { prev = newPrev; }
    void setNext(Node *newNext) { next = newNext; }
    ~Node() {}
private:
    int data;
    Node *prev;
    Node *next;
};

class DoublyList {
public:
    DoublyList(); 

    ~DoublyList();

    void destroyList();

private:
    Node *first;    // pointer to the first node on the list
    Node *last;     // pointer to the last node on the list
    int count;      // number of nodes in the list
};
```

Also these lines:

```
    current = start_ptr;

    while((current!=NULL) && (current->temp->age!=updateAge))
    {
        current=current->next;
    }
    if (current==NULL)
        {cout<<"The Requested age is Not Found" << endl;}
```

You are setting `current` to `next` in the while loop, so eventually current will become `nullptr`, so the `if` statement will be evaluated to true, which will output "The requested age is not found".

One more thing: do not use `NULL`, use `nullptr` instead.

Comment: I've posted the node class and list struct.

Comment: @Aurora you can refer to my code to construct your linked list. but i think the reason your program doesn't work is because you are redeclaring your `start_ptr` in your update function

Comment: You are right about the `node *current = start_ptr;` and I've figured out that I just need to remove all of the **temp** in the `update()`  function.